# How to read records in Spring Batch which is not qualifying for chunk region?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a requirement which i need to apply some conditions in where clause while pulling records from external system. I have configured Chunk size as 4000, since because of where condition in my query, records are not able to pull in next chunk region and is skipping to next step. Say for example my query is returning 4k records using where condition, and has processed. the next 4k records are not eligible ( the where condition is not satisfying) and reader assumes all records were pulled, but there are records still need to pull, can someone please help on this.

Comment: your question is not clear. If your query returns 4k items and your chunk size is set to 4k, your step will process only one chunk and then stops.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to have issue at batch but in your query as you have written where clause in nit satisfying . You need to change the query to fetch data